# Don't know how to convert to string and print ResultSet, SELECT statement

Tags: java, select, jdbc, resultset

This is a small piece of my code. Basically, i do not know how to print my ResultSet or turn it into string.

```
try {
  String url = "jdbc:odbc:" + "userstuff"; 
  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");
  // Gets a statement
  Statement state = con.createStatement();
  String query = "SELECT description FROM topics WHERE title = '" + title + "'";
  String query2 = "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE topic = '" + title + "'";
  // selects the description for the selected topic ( title will be referenced to the chosen topic)
  ResultSet results = state.executeQuery(query);
  // selects * of the rows from "comment" table where the topic equals the selected title.
  ResultSet results2 = state.executeQuery(query2);
  desc = results.toString();
}
```

Comment: This isn't good code.  The short answer is you should map all ResultSets into an object or data structure and close it in scope.  Learn how to use PreparedStatement; don't build up query strings manually as you do.   Google for "SQL injection" to understand why.  The ODBC bridge driver is no longer available in JDK 8.  You should not depend on it.

Comment: okay, thanks for the tips and help. I will try to improve my code, am quite new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not convert ResultSet to string neither you can print directly from ResultSet.

Following code may help you.

```
try {
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:" + "userstuff"; 

    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");

    // Gets a statement
    Statement state1 = con.createStatement();
    Statement state2 = con.createStatement();

    String query1 = "SELECT description FROM topics WHERE title = '" + title + "'";

    // selects the description for the selected topic ( title will be referenced to the chosen topic)
    ResultSet results1 = state1.executeQuery( query1 );

    while( results.next() ){

        System.out.println( results1.getString( "description" );
    }

    // selects * of the rows from "comment" table where the topic equals the selected title.
    String query2 = "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE topic = '" + title + "'";

    ResultSet results2 = state2.executeQuery( query2 );

    while( results2.next() ){

        System.out.println( results2.getString( 1 ); // here 1 is tables 1st column
        System.out.println( results2.getString( 2 ); // here 2 is tables 2nd column
    }
} Exception( SQL e){

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Oh okay i get it! Thanks for your help looks like it works so much better.